# .htaccess is not working on the server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I've been installing codeigniter on my server. I use my htaccess to remove index.php from the url. Application is working fine when on my pc. I use XAMPP.
but when i uploaded into the server it only shown the homepage, i cannot access other controller without index.php

Anyway i put all the codeigniter files in root not under the directory.

PFB my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  #Removes access to the system folder by users.
  #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php
  #controller, previously this would not have been possible.
  #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
  #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends
  #the request to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I've been configure on the config files.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://114.6.xx.xxx/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

I've been check the module rewrite is Active, with this code.

```
<?php
 if(!function_exists('apache_get_modules') ){ phpinfo(); exit; }
 $res = 'Module Unavailable';
 if(in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules()))
 $res = 'Module Available';
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>A mod_rewrite availability check !</title></head>
<body>
<p><?php echo apache_get_version(),"</p><p>mod_rewrite $res"; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

below is the result of above code.

```
Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16

mod_rewrite Module Available
```

Comment: Make sure `AllowOverride All` is present in the server/vhost config.

Comment: where is it, anyway i'm using centos 7

Comment: I've been change that one in this path  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, and restart the web servers, it seems doesn't impact

Comment: owh thanks, anyway i got wrong, should be under /var/www/html/ not /var/www, now it seems worked fine